Web Content M Query Service Principle Authentication issue
i'm trying to authenticate with a Azure Data Lake via M Query. I would do via the official connector but i didn't find a way to parametrize my credentials so i ended up here.
I want to set the url/guids via parameters with as script in the Power BI Service (app.powerbi.com).
The thing is, the data will load and show in report and after refresh locally, it won't show any errors:
PBI Service:
When i upload those reports to the Power BI Service, it won't connect an throw this error:
PBI Service
"400): Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid."
On refresh in PBI Service, i get this error: [Unable to combine data] Section1/DataSource/source references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

This is my current implementation
Access Token Query as a function:
let
    GetAccessToken = () =>
    let
        tenantId = TenantID,
        tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",

        // Create the body for the token request
        tokenBody = [
            client_id = ServicePrincipleClientID,
            client_secret = ServicePrincipleClientSecret,
            scope = "https://storage.azure.com/.default",
            grant_type = "client_credentials"
        ],

        tokenRequest = Web.Contents(tokenEndpoint, [
            Content = Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString(tokenBody)),
            Headers = [#"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
            //Timeout=#duration(0, 0, 0, 2),
            RelativePath = TenantID & "/oauth2/v2.0/token"
        ]),

        source = tokenRequest,
        tokenSource = Json.Document(tokenRequest),
        result = tokenSource[access_token]
    in
        result
in
    GetAccessToken

Data Query:
let 
    accessToken = GetAccessToken,
    UtcTimeZone = DateTimeZone.UtcNow(),
    UtcTime = DateTimeZone.RemoveZone(UtcTimeZone),
    UtcTimeText = DateTime.ToText(UtcTime, [Format="r"]),
    headers = [
            #"x-ms-version" = "2023-08-03",
            #"x-ms-date" = UtcTimeText,
            #"Authorization" = "Bearer " & accessToken
        ],
    response = Web.Contents (DataLakeURL, [
        Headers = headers,
        RelativePath = ConsumableStorage&ConsumableFileName
        ]),
    source = Text.FromBinary(response)
in 
    source

I already made sure that both queries have some privacy, that i have a relative path set, that i have the necessary permissions, but i don't know what could be missing..
The thing is, we use hierarchical namespace (dfs) and not blob, but i could access the files via Postman and also locally with my M Query.
I would be really thankful for any idea! :)

"references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source" error happens if your privacy levels aren't set. -- or an easier fix is just move your GetAccessToken into your Data Query. -- If the motivation was to cache the response -- reference query does not cache across queries. unless you're using a dataflow

Yes, i have changed that, thanks! I just then noticed, that i can't find a clear way how to pass the service principle secret without expossing it via git.. Do you see any other way to dynamically connect the data lake dynamically to the report?
